# How to create an ACTION_VIEW intent that behaves like File Manager

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to give the user an open to choose an application to open a file with. This is a PDF file I've created and saved to external using itext 5.

I've tried forcing a chooser using the code snippet below with the following result:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/JUBFf.png

```
// path = /storage/emulated/0/Documents/imagedemo.pdf
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Open with..."));
```

As you can see the list is empty. However when I try opening the same file from **File Manager** (stock app on Oxygen OS) I get the following prompt:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/fOOmn.png.

This both allows me to use the already instead **Drive** app to open the PDF and suggests other applications (**Amazon Kindle**) that might be able to open this file type as well.

How can I create a similar type of behaviour? Should I be using a different Intent action?

Comment: What exactly is `path`?

Comment: @CommonsWare I've edited the question to include the path as a code comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/storage/emulated/0/Documents/imagedemo.pdf` is not a valid `Uri`.

If you have a `File` object pointing to that location, you can use `Uri.fromFile()` to get a `Uri` pointing to it. Note that on Android 7.0+, that will fail once your `targetSdkVersion` hits 24 or higher, as the `file` scheme is banned. You can use `FileProvider` to serve this content, using `FileProvider.getUriForFile()` to get the `Uri` to use in the `Intent`.